# C# website with Apache server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, apache

I've got this scenario: I want to build a website to a friend só he can manager his business. I want to do it like it is going to be online, using C# MVC. The thing is that only my friend will use the system, on localhost:/something...

My question is: if I put the files of my app on Apache, installed in my friends computer, will he be able to access the web site thru localhost:/mysite...?

Comment: why apache? you can host in IIS in the same computer.

Comment: Maybe it's a Linux box or a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for your use case ASP .net Core makes perfect sense. Have a look at the these articles and sample

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/intro.html

https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore

Easy to run/deploy and don't need IIS Install either.

Answer (score 0):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-aspdotnet/

> mod_aspdotnet is a loadable Apache 2 module for serving ASP.NET
>   content using the Microsoft's ASP.NET hosting and .NET runtime within
>   the Apache HTTP Server process. Non-Windows users should look at mono
>   (mod_mono) for an alternate implementation.